# Can the `map` function return a vector instead of a list?

Tags: clojure

Suppose i have the following function that replaces every 0 from a sequence with a set of numbers and every other number gets placed into a set with just that number.

```
(defn helper
  [lst]
  (map #(if (zero? %) 
          (sorted-set 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
         #{%})
    lst) )
```

When i run it it returns `(#{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9} #{2} #{5} #{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9} #{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9})` but i want it to return the sets into a vector rather than a list like so: `[#{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9} #{2} #{5} #{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9} #{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}]`. What should i do so that it returns them in a vector than in a list ?

Comment: Just for reference re: your deleted question, I would write it [like this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/d996ad0dd53791a94e627d2cbd3d4f12). The key is to separate the condition from the body.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you so much, i deleted it because i was going to post a more complicated version so that i could learn more but this is exactly what i was asking for. Thanks again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `mapv`.  It is not lazy and always returns a vector.

You should also bookmark [The Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet) and always keep a browser tab open to it.  Review a few functions daily until you are familiar with all of them.  Just like learning the Java APIs, it takes a while but it is worth it.

Be sure to see this [list of Clojure documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).

Enjoy!